# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Sätzen?

Tags: standard-german, tense

Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätze nicht finden:

> 1) Das Buch wurde 1959 veröffentlicht.
>
> 2) Das Buch ist 1959 veröffentlicht worden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Unterschied liegt in der verwendeten Zeit: 1) ist Imperfekt, 2) ist Perfekt.

In Ihrer Bedeutung sind beide Sätze identisch.

Comment: Danke! Und es gibt auch einen Unterschied im Sinne des Satzes, oder?

Comment: @Anna: Das wäre die [neue] Frage _»Wann verwendet man Imperfekt, wann Perfekt?«_. Kann ich dir leider nicht beantworten. In diesem speziellen Fall bewerte ich die Verwendung von Imperfekt oder Perfekt aber als gleichrangig, ohne Unterschied in der Bedeutung.